# How to embed custom editor window inside Xcode using 'Extensions'?

Tags: xcode, xcode-extension

I am trying to embed a custom editor window inside Xcode as we have in Visual Studio IDE i.e the plugins or extensions are embedded inside the window.
At present in Xcode, the custom editor window pop-ups as a separate window.
Refer below image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0swan.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0swan.png)